# Python if elif codes to create a paycheck

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to use Python coding to create a paycheck when a user enters a said amount of hours. For under 40 hours a week of work, the standard pay is $9.25 an hour. Anything over 40 hours is rewarded a 150% of bonus(150% of 9.25 that is). I should also be able to take in hours entered in fractions and be able to print the paycheck as the output(which states the number of hours worked, pay per hour, bonus received, if any and the total salary)

So far, I have been able to successfully use the if else statement to get the final result but I do not know how to take in fractions and print the entire paycheck in the output. I am fairly new to Python and really like it a lot. Can someone please help me improvise my code and help me with fractions and printing the entire paycheck?

Here is my code so far.

```
hours = int(input('Please enter the number of hours...'))

if hours <= 40:
    hourlyWage = hours*(9.25)

elif hours > 40:
    hourlyWage = hours*(9.25*1.5)

print('Your salary is ${0}'.format(hourlyWage))
```

Thank you and help is much appreciated!

Comment: your math is wrong. if they work more than 40 hours, you're paying ALL of the hours at the bonus rate. e.g. for 48 hours, shouldn't it 40 hours * $9.25/hour + 8 hours * ($9.25 * 1.5 bonus)` instead?

Comment: I assume you mean *"improve"* your code, you appear to have been improvising it already.

Comment: I think all you need to do is change int(...) to float(...)

Comment: Marc B, yes that is correct. How do I add that to my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
hours = int(input('Please enter the number of hours...'))

hourlyWage = 9.25
bonus = 0.5
bonusThreshold = 40
bonusHours = max(0, hours - bonusThreshold)
regularSalary = hourlyWage * hours
bonusSalary = bonusHours * hourlyWage * bonus
totalSalary = regularSalary + bonusSalary

print('Worked: {0} hours.'.format(hours))
print('Pay per hour: ${0}.'.format(hourlyWage))
print('Bonus received: ${0}'.format(bonusSalary))
print('Total salary: ${0}'.format(totalSalary))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it add the bonus to the wages earned in 40 hours(which comes to $370 as fixed?) 

For example if hours worked are 45

Then (40*9.25) + (5*9.25*1.25) = 370+69.375 = 439.375

Comment: That is one way to do it. Here I calculate base salary separately (hours * hourlyWage) and bonus ((hours - 40) * hourlyWage * bonus). I made a correctment, setting bonus to 0.5 (it was wrongly set to 1.5). I did them separately because you stated you wanted to pring out how much bonus the employee received.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = float(input('Please enter the number of hours...'))
hourlyWage = hours*(9.25)
hours = hours - 40
if hours > 0:
    hourlyWage = hourlyWage + (hours*(9.25*1.5))

print('Your salary is ${0}'.format(hourlyWage))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, if a person worked, say 45 hours, it should be

(9.25*40) +(5*9.25*1.5) = 439.375

And this code is giving me a different answer....

Comment: Cody, everything under 40 is working absolutely fine, but everything over 40 is not. I guess the bonus amount percentage should be added to extra hours over 40.

Comment: @Cody Please add some explanatory to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = float(input('Please enter the number of hours...'))   
pay = hours * 9.25 + max(hours-40,0)* (9.25*1.5-9.25)
print('Your salary is ${0}'.format(pay))
```

Comment: Thank You! The answer is correct, but how do I get it to print the whole paycheck(which describes the number of hours worked, pay per hour and bonus received if any)

Comment: That will be left as an exercise for the reader :)  Hint: see geofrank's answer (which in't entirely correct b.t.w)

Answer (score 0):

Your need to format your print statement.  Here are some [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

```
hours = 50
hourly_wage = 9.25 
>>> print('Your salary is ${0:,.2f}'.format(hourly_wage * hours
                                            + max(0, hours - 40) * hourly_wage * 1.5))
```

Your salary is $601.25